# Can one use the Android ContentProvider to serve up an http response (non DB)?

Tags: android, http, response, android-contentprovider

I would like to provide the appearance of DB for my web service without storing it into the DB as a cache or middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Not that I've tried it, you could have a look at this [RESTProvider](http://github.com/novoda/RESTProvider) project which does just that.

Comment: That is a lot of work.  I was hoping for something in the SDK.  This is going to take some serious thought.